# What is "u" and "v" in this Navier Stokes implementation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

reference: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/847f/819a4ea14bd789aca8bc88e85e906cfc657c.pdf

```c
while ( simulating )
{
    get_from_UI ( dens_prev, u_prev, v_prev );
    vel_step ( N, u, v, u_prev, v_prev, visc, dt );
    dens_step ( N, dens, dens_prev, u, v, diff, dt );
    draw_dens ( N, dens );
}
```

Is u,v the same as x,y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, yes and no. According to your paper, **u and v are vector fields.**

As read on the bottom of Page 3:

`In practice we allocate two arrays for both the density and the velocity of size,`

`size=(N+2)*(N+2):static u[size], v[size], u_prev[size], v_prev[size];static dens[size], dens_prev[size];`

U and V contain an array of vectors for each 'grid'- this method takes the particles that end up at grid 'centres' and backtraces them compared to a previous snapshot. In other words:

1) Take a snapshot;

2) Run for a bit of time;

3) Take an end snapshot and look at the points that ended up in grid centres;

4) Look at where these points were at the start;

5) Draw a nice smooth line between the start and end points

6) Call it a vector.

In this paper, **u is the field of x coordinates for the vectors and v is the field of vector y coordinates.** I appreciate it's a longwinded post, but I feel I'd be being cruel just to say 'yeah sure' because it's not actually the answer.

Of course, I'm sure you'll be able to work out that `u_prev` and `v_prev` are just the coordinates before the timer started.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I am so impressed you were able to look at it and decipher the information, especially for a little ol' stack overflow post! Have a wonderful day.